# Как разделить квадрат на N одинаковых прямоугольников и получить их маски?

Tags: c#, алгоритм, математика

У меня есть ширина квадрата и количество итоговых зон, на сколько нужно разделить этот квадрат. Каким алгоритмом можно найти маски каждой из зон?

Выделил несколько фактов в этой задаче:

- Если есть ширина, то известно, сколько всего клеточек в квадрате
- Если есть общее количество клеток и количество итоговых зон, то известно, сколько клеточек в каждой зоне

Но что это дает?

Вот пара примеров:

```
Ширина - 4
Количество зон - 2

 0123
0AAAA
1AAAA
2BBBB
3BBBB

Ответ: [
   [[0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1]],

   [[1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0]]
]
```

Если зоны получатся такими, то так тоже подойдет, просто ответ будет немного другим:

```
 0123
0AABB
1AABB
2AABB
3AABB
```

```
Ширина - 6
Количество зон - 9

 012345
0AABBCC
1AABBCC
2DDEEFF
3DDEEFF
4GGHHII
5GGHHII

Ответ: [
   [[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],

   [[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],

    ...
]
```

В первом случае можно было бы идти двойным циклом по порядку и как только бы собралось нежное количество клеточек, то можно было бы к следующей зоне переходить. Но что делать со вторым случаем? Там так сделать будет нельзя, потому что возьмется только 4 первых клеток в первом ряду.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам придётся разложить длину стороны квадрата `L` на множители

```
L = w * C
L = h * R
```

`C` и `R` - это количество столбцов и строк, `w` и `h` - ширина и высота прямоугольничков зон.

При обходе в двойном цикле номер зоны (из которого можно получить букву при необходимости) из координат вычисляется так:

```
z = (y/h)*C + (x/w)
```

Деление целочисленное (в шарпе обычное деление целочисленных переменных)

Comment: Регулярная укладка - единственный способ решить задачу?

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy Ну остальное сложнее. Имеете в виду замощение кирпичиками в двух ориентациях или вообще произвольные формы плиток?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, всё отлично работает, но как можно найти C и R?

Comment: @slx0009 Если вас не волнует форма  зон, то берите любое разложение целого числа `L` на два множителя. Обычно есть желание сделать множители равными или близкими - тогда ближайшие к sqrt(L). Например, для L=48 это 6*8.

Comment: Я про замощение кирпичами в двух ориентациях. Вдруг это единственное решение для каких-то параметров?

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy Думаю, автору скорее всего нужно единообразие размера и ориентации. А для простых L всё равно нет вариантов с одинаковыми блоками, кроме Lx1

Comment: @MBo немного не понял, при N (количество зон) = 4 получается две группы из множителей `(1, 4)` и `(2, 2)`, а как доказать, что `(2, 2)`  ближе к `sqrt(N)`, чем `(1, 4)`? Можно ли взять суммы групп множителей и сравнивать их?

Comment: @slx0009 Если числа небольшие, то получить int(sqrt(N)), и проверять делимость от этого числа вниз, взять первое же подходящее (у вас сейчас от единицы вверх идет, т.е. будет взято последнее)

Answer (score 0):

Вот такой сервис получился благодаря MBo.

```
public class MasksService : ISectorsService
{
    private readonly int _size;
    
    public MasksService(int size)
    {
        _size = size;
    }
    
    public List<bool[,]> GetMasks(int n)
    {
        var (columns, rows) = GetColumnsAndRowsAmounts(n);
        var globalMask = GetGlobalMask(columns, rows);
        return BuildMasks(globalMask);
    }
   
    private List<bool[,]> BuildMasks(int[,] globalMask)
    {
        var result = new Dictionary<int, bool[,]>();
        for (var x = 0; x < _size; x++)
        for (var y = 0; y < _size; y++)
        {
            result.TryAdd(globalMask[x, y], new bool[_size, _size]);
            result[globalMask[x, y]][x, y] = true;
        }
        return result.Values.ToList();
    }
   
    private int[,] GetGlobalMask(int columns, int rows)
    {
        var result = new int[_size, _size];
        var areaWidth = _size / columns;
        var areaHeight = _size / rows;
        for (var x = 0; x < _size; x++)
        for (var y = 0; y < _size; y++)
        {
            result[x, y] = (y / areaHeight) * rows + (x / areaWidth);
        }
        return result;
    }
   
    private static (int columns, int rows) GetColumnsAndRowsAmounts(int n)
    {
        var groups = new List<(int columns, int rows)>();
        var sqrtN = Math.Sqrt(n);
        for (var i = 1; i <= sqrtN; i++)
        {
            if (n % i == 0)
            {
                groups.Add((i, n / i));
            }
        }
        return groups.OrderBy(x => Math.Abs(x.columns + x.rows - sqrtN )).First();
    }
}
```

Но последняя строка в `GetColumnsAndRowsAmounts` еще под вопросом.